# extract part of a date in a dataframe column

Tags: r, quantmod, posixct

thanks for your help in advance. i am working with the getQuote function in the quantmod package, which returns the following data frame:

[image]

is there a way to modify all the dates in the first column to exclude the time stamp, while retaining the data frame structure? i just want the "YYYY-MM-DD" in the first column. i know that if it was a vector of dates, i would use substr(df[,1],1,10). i have also looked into the apply function, with: apply(df[,1],1,substr,1,10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option not mentioned yet:

```
tt <- getQuote("AAPL")
trunc(tt[,1], units='days')
```

This returns the date in `POSIXlt`. You can wrap it in `as.POSIXct`, if you want.

Comment: Looks nice and descriptive, but actually using it is uglier: `tt[,1]=as.POSIXct(trunc(tt[,1],units="days"))` gives me "_'origin' must be supplied_"

Comment: @DarrenCook, hmm, I get no such error. I'm not very familiar with <b>quantmod</b>. When you do `str(tt)`, is the first column `Trade Time` in `POSIXct`?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde It doesn't do it for me now either (a fresh R session). Sorry, it must have been noise, something leftover in my R session.

Comment: `as.Date` would be even more succinct, and not give you a nasty `POSIXlt`

Comment: @hadley, sure, `trunc` is more general, though. and either way, if OP needs POSIXct, he'll have to convert. `as.Date` might be faster in this case...

Answer (score 2):

using `?strptime`

```
tt <- getQuote("AAPL")
tt[,1]
[1] "2013-01-16 02:52:00 CET"
as.POSIXct(strptime(tt[,1],format ='%Y-%m-%d')) ## as.POSIXct because strptime returns POSIXlt
[1] "2013-01-16 CET"
```

**EDIT**

You can use the format argument of POSIXct, but you need to convert the tt[,1] to character before.

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(tt[,1]),format ='%Y-%m-%d')
[1] "2013-01-16 CET"
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct` takes a `format` argument, you don't need `strptime` if you want a `POSIXct` object.

Comment: this looks good, i looked into strptime, too. but, how do i apply this to the entire data frame? for multiple stocks? something like: apply(tt[,1],1,strptime,format ='%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: @user1499626 you don't need to apply, just use it as in the example

Comment: @MatthewPlourde  thanks! but I prefer strptime method in this case. You can see  my update

Comment: @agstudy, oh, what does `tt[,1]` come as? from your example it looked like it was already `character`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde it is a POSIXct , and it comes from `getQuote` as the OP in his question. I mentioned strptime because the help about formatting is in strptime not in POSIXct.

Comment: +1 oh, then there are other options, `trunc` and `cut`, as well. can't check right now, but I'm curious which is fastest.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with `lubridate`

```
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)

tickers <- c("AAPL","AAJX","ABR")
df <- ldply(tickers, getQuote)
rownames(df) <- tickers

df[,"Trade Time"] <- paste(year(df[,"Trade Time"]),month(df[,"Trade Time"]),day(df[,"Trade Time"]),sep="-")
```

There might be a more elegant way of printing the date, but this is what came to me first.

Comment: You shouldn't need `as.character` in `ymd_hms` - lubridate should automatically coerce, even if it's a factor.

Comment: Hi @hadley, I'm a big fan and Rice alumnus! I tried it without the as.character and it gave me an error: `Error in parse_date_time(dates, orders, tz = tz, locale = locale, quiet = quiet) :  No formats could be infered from the training set.` The `getQuote` function returns `POSIXct`.

Comment: cool! if it's a `POSIXct` already then you could skip the `ymd_hms` step altogether.

Comment: Hadley, the first time I tried that it didn't work. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use gsub. No need to convert data type.

```
tt <- getQuote("AAPL")
tt[, 'Trade Time']<- gsub(" [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", "", tt[, 'Trade Time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as:

```
tt[,1]=as.Date(tt[,1])
```

(where tt is `tt <- getQuote("AAPL")`, as shown in the alternative answers)

The blank before the comma means "*do all rows*" and the 1 after the comma means "*operate on (just) the first column*".

I prefer this solution because it gives you a Date object, which must be exactly what you want if you are trying to strip off timestamps.

agstudy's answer give you a date *with a timezone*, and that is going to bite you the first time you run your script in a different timezone. (Aside: I got some regressions in a unit test suite when I ran them in the U.K. while there at Christmas, due to a subtle timezone assumption in my test code.)